# Move tables to appendix

Tags: tables, appendices

I have almost 100 tabular environments in my latex document and I've decided that they would be better placed in my appendix.  What is the easiest way to move them all and provide a reference to them?  I really don't want to have to copy and paste them all and then add references.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: It would be good to see what you mean by "provide a reference" to them -- and also what your tables looks like.

Comment: probably the `endfloat` package

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing the document class or much of anything else, this could be anything from a starting point to a complete solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}} % allows tables to share a page

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}

As shown in Tables~\ref{tab:one} and \ref{tab:another}, we have two variables.
\begin{table}[tb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
A & B \\
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:one} A Table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[tb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
C & D \\
5 & 6 \\
7 & 8
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:another} A Second Table}
\end{table}

\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

[image]