# How to set the options for the endfloat package, when you have to put several packages together in one usepackage{...}?

Tags: tables, floats, longtable, appendices, options

I tried something like this: [Move tables to appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286289/move-tables-to-appendix)
to move tables and figures to the appendix.

However, longtables remain before the appendix. I solved this, following the manual ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/endfloat.pdf

But now, I always get an error, if I try to use options for end float, in my case `[nomarkers,nolists]`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Currently, I get errors with all order of packages.

```
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{longtable,threeparttable,booktabs,endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
    \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{threeparttable}{table}
        \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{booktabs}{table}
```

or

```
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat,longtable,threeparttable,booktabs}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{longtable,endfloat,threeparttable,booktabs}
```

and so on.

I really would like to know what to do about this.

I did not provide an MWE, as the problem is basically the error message, that LaTeX thinks `[nomarkers,nolists]` is an option to anything else than end float!

Comment: How about putting that package in a `usepackage` of its own ?

Comment: @Elad Den if I do that, something wired happens: the long table is then the first table in the appendix (numbered 19), before table 1, 2, ...

Comment: If you want to use options when loading multiple packages at once, the options have to apply to all of the packages you load. I don't believe there's any way around that

Comment: Thanks Au101. Maybe someone is a lot more into enfloats than me, and knows how to change that settings, without specifying those 2 as options!

Comment: If it makes a difference if you use `\usepackage{abc,xy}` or `\usepackage{abc} \usepackage{xy}`, then something strange is going on with your document, as they are identical. Please add a MWE.

Comment: there is _no difference_  in using all the packages in one `\usepackage` or using separate `\usepackage` so you can always separate them and add the options individually. Or you can add the option to `\documentclass`

Comment: Sorry, can I edit my question. Meanwhile I always habe the problem described above for the separation of use packages, i.e. I can do this, but I encounter the following problem: the long table is then the first table in the appendix (numbered 19), before table 1, 2, ...

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the tables are written to a file, and then at the end this file is `\input` and processed normally. Now your tables are floating, but `longtable` is not floating. Because you have `[tb]` as position specifier on your tables, these float to the top or the bottom of the page, so they can move across the longtable. If you want to preserve the order you can `\usepackage{float}` and give your tables the `[H]` specifier. Then the order will be preserved.

And as others have observed, put the other packages out of the `[nomarkers,nolists]` options. And the line  `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{booktabs}{table}` does not make sense, as `booktabs` is not an environment.

Here is a complete example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nolists]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}} % allows tables to share a page
\usepackage{longtable,threeparttable,booktabs,endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour*{longtable}{table}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{threeparttable}{table}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}

As shown in Tables~\ref{tab:one} and \ref{tab:another}, we have two variables.
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
A & B \\
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:one} A Table}
\end{table}

\begin{longtable}{cc}
long & table \\
5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 \\
\caption{\label{tab:another} A Long Table}
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
C & D \\
5 & 6 \\
7 & 8
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:another} A Second Table}
\end{table}

\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```